# Absolute Positioning Issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can't find a title for this because it's a complicated issue.

Let's say i have this:

```
<div style="color:red;width:900px;height:250px;">
I Can Control This DIV
</div>

<div style="position:absolute;top:0px;color:green;width:40px;height:40px">
I CANNOT control this DIV
</div>
```

Is there any way for the first div to reserve it's area and the 0px should be beneath it.

I mean i want the second div to stay beneath the first div like it's inside an iframe BUT i don't want to use iframes or frames at all.

Any way? i don't have a prob if it's Javascript solution.

Thanks

Comment: If you post your full HTML or a live example and what exactly you are trying to achieve, maybe you can get a better answer?

Comment: The purpose of `position: absolute` is to have them ignore all other elements, so if you *don't* want your `div` s to ignore each other, than maybe you shouldn't be using `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose second div in `position:relative` container. This way, `top:0px` will be counted from that div and not the whole window:

http://jsfiddle.net/z9KbD/

Explanation is in definition of `position:absolute`: *Generates an absolutely positioned element, positioned relative to the first parent element that has a position other than static.*

Answer (score 0):

Can you wrap both of them in another `div` and them control that one?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the second div a `clear:both`, that should do the trick I think you are looking for. Essentially, it will act as a carriage return for that div.

On a side note, if you were looking to absolutely position an element, you will need a parent element that contains it to be relatively positioned. Chris Coyier goes over it in depth [here](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).